# PHP: Check website for responsive design

Tags: php, responsive-design, detection

is there a class/script/possibility to check websites for responsive design? It could be something like this:

```
if (is_responsive('http://www.site.tld')) {
   echo 'is responsive';
}
else {
   echo 'is not responsive';
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can scan their stylesheets for `@media` selectors

Comment: One way would be to get CSS and check whether there are media queries in there. But then again, media queries can be used for many things, you'd have to parse them and find out whether they actually respond to diiferent screen sizes.

Comment: No, because ‘responsive-ness’ is a client-side thing, and the techniques used to implement ‘responsive-ness’ aren’t solely used to add ‘responsive-ness’ to a website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possible* ways of doing this:

1. You could use JavaScript to detect if there are any media queries in your CSS then send a true/false variable to PHP using Ajax
2. Maybe even use your server-side language to read your CSS file and use RegEx to search for any media queries in the file.

These methods are not guaranteed to work and there is really no "standard", "safe" or "non-hackey" way of doing this, also you **CAN NOT** use server-side technology to directly handle media queries.

RegEx's that you can use to match `@media` rules are:

1. `^\@media\s(.*?)\{$`

   ^ = assert position at start of the string
   \@ = matches the character @ literally
   media = matches the characters media literally
   \s = match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
   .*? = matches any character (except newline)
   { = matches the character { literally
   $ = assert position at end of the string
2. `\@media\s(.*?)\{`

   \@ = matches the character @ literally
   media = matches the characters media literally
   \s = match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
   .*? = matches any character (except newline)
   { = matches the character { literally

Also you can use the `i` to make the RegEx's case insensitive (`i` only ignores the case of [a-zA-Z])

Here are four possible ways of detecting `@media` rules using RegEx:

1. `/^\@media\s(.*?)\{$/`
2. `/^\@media\s(.*?)\{$/i`
3. `/\@media\s(.*?)\{/`
4. `/\@media\s(.*?)\{/i`

Answer (score 1):

There is no regular or perfect function to do this. For checking programmatically, you can parse the stylesheets for media queries.

So to be clear, it's **not** recommend to use it, since media queries can be used for a lot of things.

If you would like to try it anyway, this might help you: `@media ?[^{]+?{`.

Comment: You don't necessarily need media queries for a site to be responsive. I think a better answer would be simply "No. This is not possible".

Comment: This will not assure the website is responsive. Imagine even 50 or more media queries in it, but all empty.

Comment: Sure your both right there, but if he feels like doing it anyway, it might help him...

Comment: you should put a warning like "the presence of media queries does not imply that the site is responsive" anyhow

Comment: I edited my anwser. But that doesn't mean I fully agree with it being imposssible. Someone with a lot of spare time could write an function wich goes beyond just checking if the media queries are present. You could parse the line and watch for the words / values of the queries. Still, users could just use a media query for a single item, but at least you know they did something for smaller screens.

Comment: What if I use JavaScript to make my site responsive? Or simply use percentage values? Responsive != "uses media queries"

Comment: Once again, I agree it won't give you an perfect answer weither a website is responsive or not. BTW if you use JavaScript to make your site responsive, you got other problems lol. Please give me a good example of a website being responsive without media queries. It would be a website full of frames or one created in 1990.

Comment: I wouldn't use such function myself, because I simply dont feel like parsing external HTML to find the CSS files and then search those files again for the queries.. That's already too much for such simple feature. But then again, someone REALLY wanting to have such function, could integrate a lot more in the function, like checking for a meta viewport tag etc..

Answer (score 1):

No technically you can't check responsiveness using PHP script as it's a client side thing.

Answer (score 0):

No! especially in PHP.
You can  try to parse CSS for media queries, or check if element sizes are set in absolute values or not.

In my opinion way to go is having some web engine running server side, and force it to render page  with different window.width, and check if document width will change with it.  Such module could be executed from php, but cannot be done in php. - and if you don't have dedicated server, forget trying such stunts.

Comment: Just came upon this.  While your answer is old, I am curious... What does having a dedicated server have to do with it?

Comment: @CRAIG putting aside whole matter of checking responsiveness (parsing for  \@media in CSS is good indicator but not ultimate answer since there can still be styles embedded in html and properties of object  changed from javascript). To be sure you would have to render page (including running js) with different window sizes (mabe also spoofing user-agent) and check if width changed properly. And it cannot be done in vanilla php. And is far outside of limitation imposed by shared hosting services. Anything less than at least virtual machine is no-go + it is resource heavy so dedicated.